# Poetry add command removes category from lock file

Tags: python, python-poetry

My current poetry.lock file looks like this (part of it)

```
# This file is automatically @generated by Poetry and should not be changed by hand.

[[package]]
name = "annotated-types"
version = "0.6.0"
description = "Reusable constraint types to use with typing.Annotated"
category = "main"
optional = false
python-versions = ">=3.8"
files = [
    {file = "annotated_types-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl", hash = "sha256:0641064de18ba7a25dee8f96403ebc39113d0cb953a01429249d5c7564666a43"},
    {file = "annotated_types-0.6.0.tar.gz", hash = "sha256:563339e807e53ffd9c267e99fc6d9ea23eb8443c08f112651963e24e22f84a5d"},
]

[[package]]
name = "asgiref"
version = "3.7.2"
description = "ASGI specs, helper code, and adapters"
category = "main"
optional = false
python-versions = ">=3.7"
files = [
    {file = "asgiref-3.7.2-py3-none-any.whl", hash = "sha256:89b2ef2247e3b562a16eef663bc0e2e703ec6468e2fa8a5cd61cd449786d4f6e"},
    {file = "asgiref-3.7.2.tar.gz", hash = "sha256:9e0ce3aa93a819ba5b45120216b23878cf6e8525eb3848653452b4192b92afed"},
]
```

For every package there is a **category**

Now I need to add an extra package. I run `poetry add --group main beautifulsoup4` , but category is removed from each line. What should I do to: 1) install a new package 2) make category fields stay the same

Comment: I am not sure, but from what i understand, the `poetry.lock` format is [not documented for now](https://github.com/orgs/python-poetry/discussions/6763), and changes with the poetry versions. That `category` field disappearing is probably normal and intended behaviour. I wouldn't worry about it (as long as the `pyproject.toml` stays correct.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*category* was removed since poetry 1.5, that is why it's removed in poetry.lock file after any changes